# Looking to plot 16,000 data points vs. Time using MatPlotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to plot a drone's altitude vs time (Time on the X-axis and altitudes on the Y-axis). I converted my list of timestamps into a MatPlotLib-readable format using `dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(timestamps)`. The length of the altitudes list and the converted timestamps list is 16587 exactly, so there is no mismatch there. The graph came out absolutely horrendous and I would like to know how to make this readable with so much data. My full code is

```
timestamps = []

for stamp in times: #convert list of timestamp Strings to Python timestamp objects
    stamp = date + " " + stamp
    stamp = stamp.replace('.', ':') # We want the milliseconds to be behind a colon so it can be easily formatted to DateTime
    stamp = datetime.strptime(stamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
    timestamps.append(stamp)

dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(timestamps)

for alt in altitudes:
    alt = round(float(alt), 2)


plt.plot_date(dates, altitudes)

plt.show()
```

[image: ugly graph]

Comment: I assume you are ok with the points but you are not ok with the ticks labels?

Comment: You forgot to convert your `altitudes` to numbers.

Comment: Yeah the times for X-axis is fine, but they are overlapping

Comment: My altitudes are floats, will that not work?

Comment: Oh, I wasn't changing the list in place!!! That fixed a lot, thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Answer (score 0):

The graph is indeed unreadable, even if it is not clear what's your expectation.

When plotting a huge number of points, I guess is better to specify also the `alpha` parameter to add some transparency and "see through" clouds of overlapping points.

Then you can specify your `x` and `yticks` (maybe also with `rotation` parameter) to show a smaller portion of them and add `plt.grid(True)`

These are just basic suggestions. Try to be more specific in "make this readable".